# What is the name of the filter or technique to reduce depth aliasing around object edges when working with camera depth?

Tags: image-processing, filter-design, 3d, point-cloud

I'm working with a point cloud, created by sampling a 2D camera texture and a depth map. The color is combined with the depth and is projected onto a 3D scene to create a "point cloud".

The resolution of the image is good, except around the object edges, where I'm running into aliasing / fraying / rounding errors like the image below.

I'm new to signal processing. Please help me understand:

**What is the name of the 3D phenomenon I'm describing?**

**What kind of filter can be applied to enforce sharp depth changes (and reject this fraying) in the projected point cloud?**

PS. It appears that if I turn off "smoothing" operation, the aliasing disappears. (But I still have the issue in another project where I can not turn if off)

[image]